# Is it possible to use multicreate with many-to-many relationships?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I understand in dbic that many-to-many isn't a real relationship and what I've done up until now is used the add_to_$rel function.

Is it possible to structure my many-to-many data in such a way that I can insert it using multicreate?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

many-to-many are not relationships but relationship helpers, see [https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship#many_to_many](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aRelationship#many_to_many).

You need to use the two underlying relationships for the data structure you're passing to create:

```
$rs->create({
    rel_to_bridge_table => {
        column_in_bridge_table => 'foo',
        rel_to_remote_table => {
            col1 => 'bar',
            col2 => 'baz',
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried to work this out but I cannot. Does anyone have an example?